# Finding an error while doing algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

While I was trying to simplify an equation, I came up with a sort of inconsistency in two identical expressions.

I want to simplify the equation$$x=-\frac{a+b}{a-b}(x+y),~\textrm{where}~ a>0,b<0$$ in a way that I have $ax+by$ on the left hand side and a factor of $x+y$ on the right hand side.

I tried two simple methods but they end up different answers and I want to know why.

Firstly, we can multiply $a-b$ on both sides. So we have$$ax-bx=-ax-ay-bx-by,$$which is the same as$$ax+by=-ax-ay=-a(x+y).$$This is the desired answer.

However, if I start by adding $ax+by$ on both sides, I should have$$ax+by=ax+by-x-\frac{a+b}{a-b}(x+y),$$which is equivalent to$$ax+by=\left (a-1-\frac{a+b}{a-b}\right )x+\left (b-\frac{a+b}{a-b}\right )y.$$To have $ax+by=-a(x+y)$, it should be that$$a-1-\frac{a+b}{a-b}=-a~\textrm{and}~b-\frac{a+b}{a-b}=-a,$$which does not seem to be correct statements. Could anyone spot my error in manipulating the equation?

Comment: Please tag your question properly.

Comment: @user1551 Sorry. I couldn't find proper tags. Thank you for the update.

Comment: In your 2nd method, please edit your posting to carefully show your work, line by line.  When I *added* $(ax+by)$ to both sides, I got $$ax + by + x = \left[\frac{-a-b}{a-b} + 1\right] (x+y)$$ $$= \frac{-2b}{a-b}(x+y).$$  Assuming that you agree with this, please very carefully show your work, in your 2nd method, from this point on.

Comment: $ax+by=-ax-ay$, can I conclude that $a=-a$, $b=-a$. Problem is that $x$ and $y$ are not independent quantities.

Comment: Your last line should be for the 2 right hand sides:
$... = a$ and $... = b$. Which will easily simplify.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu, Yeah, that was the problem :) I got it now. Thank you for the comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last statement is wrong. We can write the right hand side as $$\alpha(x+y)+\beta(ax+by)$$You have then $$(ax+by)(1-\beta)=\alpha(x+y)$$or $$ax+by=\frac{\alpha}{1-\beta}(x+y)$$
So all you need is to find $\alpha$ and $\beta$. This is a simple linear system with two equations and two unknowns. I get $$\alpha=-\frac a{a-b}\\\beta=1-\frac 1{a-b}$$
Therefore $$ax+by=-a(x+y)$$

Comment: Oh, thank you so much. I got it. So, I should've found $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that satisfies $\alpha(x+y)+\beta(ax+by)=ax+by-x-(a+b)(x+y)/(a-b)$. I could reach the same answer as in my first approach!

Comment: Correct. But I would use the same approach directly in the first equation.